# Export file keeps on adding HTML codes even with ob_end_clean()

Tags: php

Export file keeps on adding HTML codes. Did a research already with stackoverflow to add ob_end_clean(). Still it outputs the HTML codes on the exported file. I want the data to be exported in a clean csv file without the html codes. Please help. Thank you

```
    <?php

    function exportMysqlToCsv($table,$filename)
    {
        $csv_terminated = "\n";
        $csv_separator = ",";
        $csv_enclosed = '"';
        $csv_escaped = "\\";
        $sql_query = "select * from $table";

        // Gets the data from the database
        $result = mysqli_query($sql_query);
        $fields_cnt = mysqli_num_fields($result);


        $schema_insert = '';

        for ($i = 0; $i < $fields_cnt; $i++)
        {
            $l = $csv_enclosed . str_replace($csv_enclosed, $csv_escaped . $csv_enclosed,
                stripslashes(mysqli_field_name($result, $i))) . $csv_enclosed;
            $schema_insert .= $l;
            $schema_insert .= $csv_separator;
        } // end for

        $out = trim(substr($schema_insert, 0, -1));
        $out .= $csv_terminated;
        ob_end_clean(); //<------------------------------------OB_END_CLEAN
        // Format the data
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {

            $schema_insert = '';
            for ($j = 0; $j < $fields_cnt; $j++)
            { 
                if ($row[$j] == '0' || $row[$j] != '')
                {

                    if ($csv_enclosed == '')
                    {
                        $schema_insert .= $row[$j];
                    } else
                    {
                        $schema_insert .= $csv_enclosed .
                        str_replace($csv_enclosed, $csv_escaped . $csv_enclosed, $row[$j]) . $csv_enclosed;
                    }
                } else
                {
                    $schema_insert .= '';
                }

                if ($j < $fields_cnt - 1)
                {
                    $schema_insert .= $csv_separator;
                }
            } // end for

            $out .= $schema_insert;
            $out .= $csv_terminated;
        } // end while

        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Content-Length: " . strlen($out));
        // Output to browser with appropriate mime type, you choose ;)
        header("Content-type: text/x-csv");
        //header("Content-type: text/csv");
        //header("Content-type: application/csv");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
        echo $out;
        exit;

    }

    ?>
```

The code above is being called by another php file containing HTML codes such as the html,head and body tags. here is the code used to call the function after being triggered by a submit button:

```
    if(isset($_POST['export'])){
        date_default_timezone_set ("Asia/Manila");  
        $date = date('YmdHis');
        exportMysqlToCsv('rfc_bisar_b2h_upl_log','BISAR-AUDIT-'.$date.'.csv');
    }
```

Comment: there is no html in that code, so were is ot coming from?

Comment: Where is your `ob_start() `?

Comment: @Dagon this PHP code is being called from another PHP file that contains HTML Codes.

Comment: @Tristan where should I put the ob_start()?

Comment: At the very start of your script execution to start output buffering before any other php or html code could be sent to the browser

Comment: you dont need output buffering at all, but without see all the code ...

Comment: @Dagon the file call the above code contains HTML codes such as <html><body> etc... the way I call it after including it include('export.php') is:  
  if(isset($_POST['export'])){
   date_default_timezone_set ("Asia/Manila"); 
   $date = date('YmdHis');
   exportMysqlToCsv('rfc_bisar_b2h_upl_log','BISAR-AUDIT-'.$date.'.csv');
  }

Comment: just put this in its own file, and call the link `if(isset($_POST['export'])){ header('Location: http://www.example.com/export.php');exit;}`

Comment: @Dagon I have edited my question. Please see the second paragraph and sample code. The main page contains the data outputted for users to see the table contents from mysql. There is a submit button there that lets the user export the data into csv file. The first set of codes above does the exporting but contains html codes. I dont want users to get redirected to another page when clicking export button. so I call the function from another file and prevent the system from redirection.

Comment: well im saying dont do it that way as you have already ouput headers you need a new http call

Comment: @Dagon please see my edited comment 10 mins ago. thanks

Comment: You dont actually get redirected as the output is a csv file (the browser will prompt a download), not html. one page request can only have one content type, you cant serve HTML and csv in the same request

Answer (score 0):

To use output buffering you must place `ob_start()` at the start of script execution otherwise `ob_end_clean()` will not work.

```
<?php
ob_start();

// your code

// clean any output before outputting
ob_end_clean();

// output here
```

Comment: returns the csv file without contents